# Svg to map marker with text overlay

Tags: google-maps, svg, flutter

I have a task to build a map with markers that can have dynamic content (text or icon) on top (as overlay layer) I'm trying to achieve this with google_maps_flutter and flutter_svg libs.

Generally my idea is to get marker svg convert it into Image add extra layers (Found DrawableRoot class) convert to bytes and pass to BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes() in Marker constructor

The problem is that I'm failing on first step when I just trying to use svg as marker.
I create bytes from my svg string like this:

```
Future<Uint8List> svg() async {
    final raw = r'''<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'><svg enable-background="new 0 0 40 52" height="52px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 40 52" width="40px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><path d="M20.421-0.125c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20s20,32,20,32s20-20.954,20-32S31.467-0.125,20.421-0.125z    M20.421,27.875c-5.522,0-10-4.477-10-10s4.478-10,10-10s10,4.477,10,10S25.943,27.875,20.421,27.875z" fill="#231F20"/><path d="M20.421,11.875c-3.309,0-6,2.691-6,6s2.691,6,6,6s6-2.691,6-6S23.729,11.875,20.421,11.875z" fill="#231F20"/></g></svg>''';
    final pictureInfo = await svg.svgPictureStringDecoder(raw, false, null, raw);
    final image = await pictureInfo.picture.toImage(36, 36);
    final byteData = await image.toByteData();
    final uint8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return uint8List;
  }
```

And then after passing the result to marker constructor all I get is "default" red marker.

```
Future<Iterable<Marker>> convertPlacesToMarkers(Iterable<Place> places) async {
final markerBytes = await UITools.convertSvg();
return places
    .map((place) => Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(place.id),
      position: place.latlng,
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerBytes),
      onTap: () => onBusStopMarkerTap(place)))
    .toList();
```

}

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes takes bytes encoded as PNG. Please try

```
final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
```

I'm also using a slightly different method of getting DrawableRoot, using svg.fromSvgString():

```
DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgString, null);
Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture();
Image image = await picture.toImage(36, 36);
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rednuht's answer is still correct (Aug 2020) with one exception: Size has to be specified in DrawableRoot.toPicture() otherwise Picture isn't scaled by Picture.toImage();

```
Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture(size: Size(36.0,36.0));
```